# Connection from C # code with SQL Server 2014 Express does not work , can not open the connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, sql-server-express

I am creating a client in WPF with C # , and I need to install it on the client ( tablet surface ) . That said , I installed SQL Server 2014 Express edition , just to get the instance , I've downloaded from here :

https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42299

and i get this:

> Express 64BIT\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe

I installed everything, of course I do not have the managament of SQL Server interface , but I can not create the db , here is my error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

this is my connection string (get this from constants file):

> Server=SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Integrated security=true;

and this is my code:

```
 public void CreateDatabase(String PID)
        {
            String connection = Constants.localServerConnectionSQL.LocalServerConnectionSQLName;
            SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection();
            Connection = new SqlConnection(connection);
            Connection.Open();

            string Path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LocalAppData") + @"\CDA\UserDatabase\" + PID.ToString();
            log.Info("DBCreationScripts: Path DB: " + Path.ToString());

            String str = "CREATE DATABASE [" + PID + "] ON PRIMARY " +
           "(NAME = MyDatabase_Data, " +
           "FILENAME = '" + Path + ".mdf', " +
           "SIZE = 5MB, MAXSIZE = 10MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%) " +
           "LOG ON (NAME = [" + PID + "Log_Log], " +
           "FILENAME = '"+Path+"Log.ldf', " +
           "SIZE = 1MB, " +
           "MAXSIZE = 5MB, " +
           "FILEGROWTH = 10%)";

            log.Info("DBCreationScripts: Comando di creazione DB: " + str);


            try
            {
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, Connection);
                log.Info("DBCreationScripts: Lancio il comando di creazione database");
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                log.Info("DBCreationScripts: Eccezione nel comando di creazione database -  Message: " + ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that it fails to open the connection , the instance is SQLEXPRESS , but do not understand why colleagues are not . E ' can I have configured something wrong ?

The SQL services are all active .

Tips ?

Comment: Data Source=[DBInstance];Initial Catalog=[Database];User Id=[User];Password=[Password];MultipleActiveResultSets=True

Comment: You aren't trying to connect to the SQLEXPRESS instance, you are trying to connect to the machine called SQLEXPRESS. Fix your connection string and use a proper instance name, eg `.\SQLEXPRESS` or `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` or `that.other.name\SQLEXPRESS`. And *please* don't use string concatenation to create SQL scripts, unless you want a Bobby Tables (aka SQL Injection attack)

Comment: @MarcoBong using `Data Source` instead of `Server` won't help. The error isn't about the syntax and `Server` *is* a valid synonym to `Data Source`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos your comment is the solution, if you answer the question i set it right...Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to refer to a SQL Server instance is `Server Address\Instance Name`, eg `MyServer\SQLExpress`, `.\SQLEXPRESS` or `127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS`.

Without the backslash, the text is interpreted as the machine name. A connection string with `Server=SQLEXPRESS` will try to connect to a server named `SQLEXPRESS`.